# Wildfly classloading: it's better from modules or from ear dependency?

Tags: java, wildfly

I've an EAR project that contains a lot of dependencies.
Some dependencies are big jar (more than 4 mb), so i preferred to install them as modules on wildfly and add a module-dependency in jboss-deployment.xml.

For istance we have org.mypackage.MyClass, it's better to load that class from a regular dependency inside the ear/lib dir or from JBOSS_HOME/module ? Are there loss of efficiency?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wilfly Doc:

### Class Loading Precedence

A common source of errors in Java applications is including API classes in a deployment that are also provided by the container. This can result in multiple versions of the class being created and the deployment failing to deploy properly. To prevent this in WildFly, module dependencies are added in a specific order that should prevent this situation from occurring.

In order of highest priority to lowest priority

- System Dependencies - These are dependencies that are added to the
  module automatically by the container, including the Java EE api's.
- User Dependencies - These are dependencies that are added through
  jboss-deployment-structure.xml or through the Dependencies: manifest 
  entry.
- Local Resource - Class files packaged up inside the deployment
  itself, e.g. class files from WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib of a
  war.
- Inter deployment dependencies - These are dependencies on other
  deployments in an ear deployment. This can include classes in an
  ear's lib directory, or classes defined in other ejb jars.

More on: [Class Loading in Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly)

Comment: I'd love to know how this answers the two questions in the last paragraph of the OP.

Comment: @SteveC I suppose that if modules are added prior to inter deployment dependencies, the classes are found faster. It's a my opinion, am'I wrong?

Comment: Class loading speed is not normally a problem, even in huge applications.